# Mongo Query to search one or more values are present in an array field of a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like below

```
  {

  _id: ObjectId(),

  account_number: someID,

  account_context: {acnt_id:"1234",acnt_name:"Akhil",address:"Kadapa"},

  tags:["tag","TaG","User","tag2","usr"]

},

{

  _id: OBjectId(),

  account_number: someID,

  account_context: {acnt_id:"1234",acnt_name:"Akhil",address:"Kadapa"},

  tags:["gat","GaT","Hello","tag2","Usr"]

}
```

I would like to query based on tags.
If I search for "tag" and "gat" , I should get both the documents
If I search for "Tag" , I should get first document
If I search for "tag" and "Hello", I should get both the documents.

Which means if the search field match for any one of the array element in the document I should get that document.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$elemMatch` with `$in` for this problem like it:

```
var searchedArray = ["tag","Hello"]
collection.find({
    tags: {$elemMatch: {$in:searchedArray}}
}, (err, result)=>{

})
```

`$elemMatch` check all elements of an array with her expression. my expression is `$in` that check filed with all values is there in `searchedArray` if equal accept it.

Comment: @PolaiahBodeddula if is correct answer set as accepted.